# Trying to protect pages unless signed in Nuxt JS & Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

I'm playing around with this Nuxt Firebase Auth package I found on Github (https://github.com/james2doyle/nuxt-firebase-auth) which uses the latest version of Nuxt JS & Firebase, as well as Firebase Auth.

I have my application setup with the Email/Password option and am trying to protect pages, essentially I want to redirect a user away from a page unless they're signed in.

I've tried a few ways of doing this with little luck. I'm new to Auth in Firebase and Nuxt JS and would like to be pointed in the right direction.

I have a page set up called `secret.vue` but this could be any page, my code for this page follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    secret page
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  middleware: 'anonymous',
  watch: {
    user (to, from) {
      this.$router.push('/account/login')
    }
  },
  computed: mapState([
    'user'
  ])
}
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Many thanks